# How to show a row number column in slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid

I am displaying some data in a slickgrid using ajax call which looks similar like this.

*india 564*

*usa 45454*

*japan 5454*

There is no column called a 'Number' which have the row number values,in the data table I am fetching. How can I set a column called 'Number' and set values? What I want is something similar like this.

*1 india 564*

*2 usa 45454*

*3 japan 5454*

Comment: Since it isn't in your data, there is no reason to have this number persist across page loads, so I would just add a property to the objects when you receive them from the ajax. Then just add a column based on that prop

Answer (score 6):

To display the row number, you don't need a specific field/property for it. You can define a column and specify the [formatter column option](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options) to return a  value based on the underlying indexing of the grid which the function receives as it's first argument. Since the grid is 0 index based, adjust accordingly.

```js
var grid;
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
var data = [{country: "usa", number: "123"},
    {country: "japan", number: "456"},
    {country: "india", number: "789"}];
    
var options = {
    editable: false,
    enableCellNavigation: true
};
var columns = [{name: "Row No", formatter: function(row){return row+1}},
    {field: "country", name: "Country"},
    {field: "number", name: "Data"}];

dataView.setItems(data, 'country')
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/examples.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
<script src="http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.dataview.js"></script>    
    
<div id="myGrid" style="width:300px;height:150px;"></div>
```